# Eliminar comilla sencilla de un string en java

Tags: java, string

Tengo el siguiente codigo

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String cadena ="'--7'";
        String cadenalimpia = "";
        String val = "'";
        String rep = "";
        cadena.replaceAll ("'", "");
        cadenalimpia = cadena;
        System.out.println(cadenalimpia);
    }
}
```

pero no me elimina la comilla sencilla y sigue saliendo   '--7'

como puedo eliminar las comillas y que quede solo --7

Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los `String` son inmutables. Por es razón `replaceAll()` devuelve una nueva cadena y no modifica el valor de `cadena`.

```
cadena = cadena.replaceAll ("'", "");
```